# Ext Net TimeField in an editable grid

Tags: ext.net

I have a grid panel which display two TimeSpans in two columns and all is well when I load the page but when I go server side the validation on my editors always fail. I don't understand why the store can display the TimeSpans but cannot return it after...

Here my code :

```
<ext:GridPanel ID="WeekParams" runat="server" >
    <Store>
        <ext:Store runat="server">
            <Reader>
                <ext:JsonReader IDProperty="GUID">
                    <Fields>
                        <ext:RecordField Name="Day" Type="String" />
                        <ext:RecordField Name="UATNumber" Type="int" />
                        <ext:RecordField Name="From" Type="Date" />
                        <ext:RecordField Name="To" Type="Date" />
                    </Fields>
                </ext:JsonReader>
            </Reader>
        </ext:Store>
    </Store>
    <ColumnModel>
        <Columns>
            <ext:Column ColumnID="Day" DataIndex="Day" />
            <ext:NumberColumn ColumnID="UATNumber" DataIndex="UATNumber" Format="0" />
            <ext:DateColumn ColumnID="From" DataIndex="From" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" >
                <Renderer Format="Date" FormatArgs="'HH:mm'" />
                <Editor>
                    <ext:TimeField runat="server" />
                </Editor>
            </ext:DateColumn>
            <ext:DateColumn ColumnID="To" DataIndex="To" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" >
                <Renderer Format="Date" FormatArgs="'HH:mm'" />
                <Editor>
                    <ext:TimeField runat="server" />
                </Editor>
            </ext:DateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </ColumnModel>
    <Plugins>
        <ext:EditableGrid runat="server" />
    </Plugins>
</ext:GridPanel>
```

And here the result when I'm going to the server side :

[image]

Comment: I can investigate, if a full runnable test case is available.

Comment: Thanks Daniil but I have resolve my problem by using a row editor instead.